# AngularJs set $setPristine to false

Tags: angularjs

I have a situation where I want to set $setPristine to false. In a form, I have a multi-select dropdown which does not get validated by the $pristine. I have written a separate event to validate the changes in multi-select dropdown, but the $pristine still validates my screen to 'true', which is not I expected to do. At the same time, I could not remove the $pristine as it validates the other fields in the form.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="correctProperty()" ng-disabled="entityPropertyForm.$pristine || propertyCorrected || dropDownChanged">Save</button>
```

The whole ng-disabled condition not working as expected because the $pristine is 'true' even after the multi-select dropdown is changed. Can we set $setPristine to false in angularjs ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$setDirty()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setDirty) method of the Angular FormController, this will make the form's `$dirty` property `true` and the `$pristine` property false.

It's not exactly clear where you should do this from the code you've shown, but when the user interacts w/the menu you can do:

```
$scope.entityPropertyForm.$setDirty();
```

If you are using the `controllerAs` syntax, you need to prefix your form's name with the name of the controller:

```
<form name="myController.entityPropertyForm">
...
</form>
```

And then the controller code would be:

```
this.entityPropertyForm.$setDirty();
```